Import images vs include them inline NextJS
In NextJS, what is the difference between importing an image and including it directly when using next/image?
import logo from './logo.png';
<Image src={logo} />

/* versus */

<Image src={'/logo.png'} />

(Pseudocode for illustrative purposes, not syntactically correct)
Are there any speed optimizations or extra features when doing it one way or another? The import syntax makes me think that something else is going on at build time, but I can't seem to find any further details.

Take a look at the docs:

Must be one of the following:

A statically imported image file
A path string. This can be either an absolute external URL, or an internal path depending on the loader prop.
When using an external URL, you must add it to remotePatterns in next.config.js


And here about local and remote images.
Long story short:
import logo from './logo.png';
<Image src={logo} />

logo.png file stored next to the component from where you imported it. during build process next.js will move it to dist folder, determine width and height attributes of the image and set it to the component. this will help to avoid layout shift from the image loading.
When you provide static path to image:
<Image src={'/logo.png'} />

You basically tell next that this is a remote image, and it should be loaded from either next public folder, or from the remote location. (in case of /logo.png in order to be displayed image should be located here: public/logo.png). In this case you should either set image width and height properties manually, or configure remote patterns if you want to enable image next optimisation.

OK. I wish I could <Image src={require('./logo.png').default} />, so I can put the image next to the component file, without giving it a name.
